# In python, how can I error intelligibly when a removed class is subclassed by the user?

Tags: python

I'm trying to update [`django_pyodbc`](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/) for django 1.8 and it turns out that `SQLDateCompiler` was removed from django completely in version 1.8.  `django_pyodbc` is extending `SQLDateCompiler` (let's call it `SQLDateCompilerPrime`) which now no longer exists.

I want to issue a deprecation error/exception when a user inherits from `SQLDateCompiler` *before* the class is instantiated.

I'm aware of how to use python's [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) library to raise an exception, but how can I raise an intelligible exception before the class is even used. I.e. as  soon as a subclass is *defined*.

I could do:

```
class SQLDateCompilerPrime(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn(
            'In the 1.8 release of django, `SQLDateCompiler` was removed.  ' +
            'This was the basis of `SQLDateCompilerPrime`, and thus ' +
            '`SQLDateCompilerPrime` is no longer available.',
            DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

However, this will only fail when an instance of a subclass is created.  I want to fail when the subclass is *defined* and issue the warning straight away.  Removing the definition entirely would certainly cause a failure, but I don't want the user to have to look in other `django_pyodbc` to figure out that it is no longer defined and that it just disappeared right out from under them.

Comment: You can probably use a metaclass to do this, since classes are instances of their metaclass.

Comment: This is where metaclasses are for, but you should note that they will be executed at import time. So if the module is being imported but not used it will still show the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a metaclass for this:

```
class DeprecatedMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # if the metaclass is defined on the current class, it's not
        # a subclass so we don't want to warn.
        if attrs.get('__metaclass__') is not cls:
            print 'deprecated:', name
        return super(DeprecatedMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = DeprecatedMeta


class Bar(Foo):
    pass


class FooBar(Bar):
    pass
```

This example results in the following output:

```
deprecated: Bar
deprecated: FooBar
```

Comment: I believe comparing actual classes (not instances) for equality is a valid case for `is`. While both operators do the job here, I actually want to check "is the metaclass in that dict exactly THIS metaclass"